# page_load another handler?

Tags: asp.net

can someone please explain why this code is not working as expected:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class temp : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("foo<br>");
        this.Load += new EventHandler(temp_Load);

    }

    void temp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("bar<br>");
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

trying to add another handler for page Load event so that output would be:

```
foo<br>
bar<br>
```

**EDIT:**

> The actual object disappears and is
>   recreated on postback. – ggonsalv

so how can i than modify the method in memory so it makes new objects with that modified method?

for example i want to modify or add page_init handler on runtime for the next time the page loads?

Comment: You need to define your problem better. I am still trying to come up with analogy that defines your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register it in the Page_Init. By the time Page_load fires, it  is toooooo late.

Comment: but if i register page load handler in existing page load handler isn't it suppouse to persist when i click refresh button and than be triggered?

Comment: The actual object disappears and is recreated on postback.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the Load handler from withing the handler itself. It's too late as it is already executing. Why not simply calling a function as it doesn't make much sense of having multiple load handlers for the same page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("foo<br>");
    temp_Load(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: can i register handler in <% %> tags in .aspx file? code inseide those happen before page_load handling as i understand

Comment: No you can't, code inside aspx pages executes much later than Page_Load. I would suggest you looking at the ASP.NET page lifecycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx